# Why unlink function will not delete old image when uploading image

Tags: php, mysqli

I have to manually go into my folder every time I update an image. The image will update to a new image. However, when I update an image, the old image is not being deleted. I am using the PHP function unlink to delete the image but for some reason its not working. I have removed the at "@" sign from php unlink in the code. I have re-edited coded the code. I keep getting the following error:

Warning: unlink(picture/): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload_update\New_project\edit_image.php on line 24

I am trying to teach myself php, Thank you so much for your help.

This is the code:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$vid="";
$vname="";
$vprice="";
$vpicture="";



if(isset($_POST["button_edit"])){
     $product_name = $_POST["product_name"];
     $product_price = $_POST["product_price"];
     $product_id = $_POST["product_id"];
     $old_picture = $_POST['old_picture'];
     if(!empty($_FILES["product_picture"]["name"])) {
    $product_picture = $_FILES["product_picture"]["name"];
    $qry = mysqli_query($con,"Update table_product Set product_name='$product_name', product_price='$product_price', product_picture='$product_picture' Where product_id='$product_id'");

        $target_dir = "picture/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["product_picture"]["name"]);
       $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["product_picture"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);
    if (isset($old_picture) && ($old_picture != $product_picture)) {
              unlink("picture/" . $old_picture);
            }
    }
    else{
 $qry = "Update table_product Set product_name='$product_name', product_price='$product_price' Where product_id='$product_id'";
}

$qryUpdate = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    }

else if(isset($_GET["edit"])){
    $qry = mysqli_query($con,"Select * From table_product Where product_id='".$_GET["edit"]."'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $vid=$row["product_id"];
        $vname=$row["product_name"];
        $vprice=$row["product_price"];
        $vpicture=$row["product_picture"];
    }
}
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Product</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Product ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $vid;?>"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Product Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_name"  value="<?php echo $vname;?>"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Product Price</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_price"  value="<?php echo $vprice;?>"></td></tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="old_picture" value="<?php if (!empty($old_picture)) echo $old_picture; ?>" />
        <tr><td>Product Picture</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="product_picture" ></td></tr>
        <?php if (!empty($old_picture)) {
        echo '<img class="profile" src="picture/' . $old_picture . '" alt="image" style=width:150px;height:xpx;">';
      } ?>
        <tr><td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="button_add" value="Add">
        <input type="submit" name="button_edit" value="Edit"></td></tr> </table>
</form>
<table border=1>
    <tr><th>product ID</th><th>product Name</th>
    <th>product price</th><th>product image</th>  <th>Action</th></tr>
    <?php
    $qry =mysqli_query($con, "Select * From table_product");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row["product_id"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["product_name"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["product_price"].'</td>';
        echo '<td><img src="picture/'.$row["product_picture"].'" style=width:100px;height:xpx;"/></td>';

        echo '<td><a href="?edit='.$row["product_id"].'&picture='.$row["product_picture"].'">Edit</a> </td></tr>';



    }



    ?>
</table>
<br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you didn't suppress errors perhaps you would find out why

Comment: most likely it is a permission issue. look at the folder and the file permissions

Comment: "Undefined index: picture" means in your $_GET request, there is no variable called picture. Since this is in a code block where you are checking for a $_POST request, my guess is that GET variables were not set on that request. Short answer: Check if there's anything in your URL after a question mark `?`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove `@` sign from this line:

```
@unlink("picture/".$_GET["picture"])
```

this may show you warnings. 
Use absolute path to file you want to unlink, not relative so your `unlink` should look like that

```
@unlink(__DIR__."/picture/".$_GET["picture"]);
```

Comment: I have removed the at "@" sign from php unlink in the code. These are the 2 error I keep getting:

Notice: Undefined index: picture in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload_update\New_project\edit_image.php on line 22

Warning: unlink(picture/): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload_update\New_project\edit_image.php on line 22 . Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check if your $_GET array contains 'picture' index, cause, warning tells you that this index is not present in $_GET